# Imported declaration warning in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift

When I run my code, Xcode 11 shows some warnings, like:

> <unknown>:0: warning: imported declaration 'UITableViewDiffableDataSourceCellProvider' could not be mapped to 'UITableViewDiffableDataSourceReference.CellProvider'
>   <unknown>:0: warning: imported declaration 'UICollectionViewDiffableDataSourceCellProvider' could not be mapped to 'UICollectionViewDiffableDataSourceReference.CellProvider'.

How can I solve these warnings?

I run my code in Xcode 11, and It runs well in Xcode 10.

No code. If you want, I can show what you want.

I want to solve these warnings.

Comment: Is it still happening with Xcode 11 beta 2?

Comment: Yes. at least in my experience

Comment: Having the same issue on beta 2

Comment: None of the answers worked for me except the one that got deleted: Command-Shift-K. I don't know why manually cleaning out the derived data folder didn't fix it, but it didn't.

Comment: Issue still happening on Xcode 11 beta 3

Answer (score 22):

Go to:
Preferences > location > commandLine tools [drop down]
Select:
Latest version of Xcode 11.0 (...)

Answer (score 9):

Clean your build folder and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

The weird workaround that is working for me is to compile the project selecting an older simulator (in my case 10.3.1) first. When build succeeds you can select and launch the app on any iOS 13 simulator.

‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

In my case, they are 2 ways to get rid of this warning:

1. set the simulator to iPhone Xs before building your app, this is just a workaround.
2. If your code imports UIKit by "import" in Swift or by "#import " in OC, and indeed the UITableViewDiffableDataSourceCellProvider and other 2 modules are not deployed by your code, then try to replace "#import " with "@import UIKit;" in OC, while "@import UIKit" in swift. Because "@import" allows you only imports modules which are really used by your implementation.

Answer (score -3):

Try to comment `#import <UIKit/UIDiffableDataSource.h>` in 
`UIKitCore.h` header. Helped for me.